# Why has the Stack Overflow inbox become so ugly?

Tags: discussion, global-inbox

Today I placed a comment on one of the threads.

I got 2 replies from the OP and saw the number "2" in my Inbox indicator.

However when I click on it, I saw only one (1) new message (the one that was not being read).

Is there a reason for that? The second message could have an important info and I had to go open the "last" message and then scroll up the thread to read both replies.

P.S.: I already reported that the number of messages is not being decreased with the reading of the messages and someone replied that it probably will be restored, but it is not yet being done.

---

According to Makyen - "because only one of the notifications is cleared when you click on the single visible entry in the inbox".

The issue is that this selected item will NOT become cleared, unless he meant something completely different from what MOST people would think.

I just found even worse situation.

If I have a reply and my counter is 1:

I open an Inbox, right click on the reply and open it in the new TAB. I read it, reply or not and then in the same tab I click "Mark All Read". The counter in that tab becomes 0 and the envelope icon changes.

So far so good.

Now I close this tab and am back in the original tab.

The Inbox is still open with the unread message, but the counter is now becomes 0.

It is inconsistent at best and very confusing.

TIA!!

Comment: The main issue you're reporting, only showing one entry in the inbox for the post on which there's more than one comment which notify you on a post, is the way the inbox has always worked. With the inbox update, about 6 months ago now, it became *much* more obvious that this was the case, because only one of the notifications is cleared when you click on the single visible entry in the inbox. This has been reported multiple times in the last six months.

Comment: Other than that it's confusing, it's unclear from your question here how you think it should be working. You should have been able to click on "refresh (1)" in the inbox to show the notification which wasn't previously displayed, which would allow you to click on it to open the page, again, but to have the other comment that notified you be the one that is focused.

Comment: Related on MSE: "[Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/271271)"

Comment: @Makyen, I believe in the past clicking the unread post will bring me to the top reply, not the bottom one. And the count should be cleared - but that the different issue now... And now I shouldn't have to click anywhere - the count has to drop to 1, until I open the second reply with the same scenario. Or even better drop to 0 because I now read all replies that is addressed to me. I can live with both, but second is preferred.

Comment: @Makyen, `Related on MSE: "Inbox improvements are live"` - except they are not improvements - they are deprovements... ;-)

Comment: @Makyen, BTW, even if I click on `Refresh` link in the Inbox, the count is NOT decreased. I have to go and click the little envelope icon to decrease the Inbox counter.

Comment: Yes, the refresh link just refreshes the displayed inbox to the current state. If you're wanting to clear all the notifications, you can click "Mark all as read". It used to be that "Mark all as read" was effectively clicked when you closed the inbox popup.

Comment: @Makyen, the thing is - I didn't have to do that. It was done automatically. Because the presumption is - I am reading the reply and so the count shuold become `N - 1`. And as I said - I should go to the first reply on the thread, not the last one.

Comment: @Makyen, "because only one of the notifications is cleared when you click on the single visible entry in the inbox" - this is the problem - this entry is NOT cleared. I don't know what you mean by `cleared`, but for me the word `cleared` means that the item becomes `read`. What do YOU mean by that word?

Comment: @Igor: I believe that's what Makyen means as well. The inbox typically merges together multiple unread notifications (or multiple read notifications) of the same type from the same post, so that only the most recent one is visible. As Makyen points out, the issue is that the single unread notification that's visible in the inbox is marked as read when you left-click or middle-click on it – but other unread notifications that have also been merged into it are not also marked as read when this happens.

Comment: (The other potential point of confusion is that the number on the inbox icon matches the actual number of unread notifications, but some of these may not be visible because they've been merged into other unread notifications from the same post.) As Makyen points out, these issues have been previously reported, and the devs are planning to fix them.

Comment: @V2Blast, for years I did the following: open the Inbox, right click on the unread message, and click open in the new tab. This action opens up the new tab with the first reply to my message, clears the count to 0 and all those messages becomes "read". Now this action opens the last reply, do not clear the counter and do not mark the messages (ALL of them) as "read". See the difference?

Comment: For me this is a huge step back. The reason being - on the SO I am having a tag open 24/7. At times I may have ask question(s) on other sites: Linux, Apple, DB Admin, etc. So all I'm doing is `opening the TAB with the reply`. Its simple, convenient and easy. Now without clearing the messages I have to either do it manually or keep clicking "Refresh Page". -> extra unneeded work IMHO.

Comment: Duplicate of this? [Inbox notifications not consistently marked as read after clicking title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424147/7395227)

Comment: _"this selected item will NOT become cleared"_ - make it clearer that this is your problem. I find that annoying as well, when scroll-clicking notifications to open their posts in new tabs.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I 200% agree. I just updated the OP with another ugliness/inconsistency. If you care to comment - be my guest.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship, I just added ano0her inconsistency. If ou want you cam comment.

Comment: Yeah this is a problem since a while back. Typical scenario/example: I log in and see the number 5. This number can refer to 3 new notifications and 2 old from yesterday which I have definitely read. Then I open up the 3 which are definitely new one by one. After doing that, hitting refresh and blaming caching, I might end up with the number 1, where 1 points at one of the 3 new posts which I have all opened and read. Thus: glitchy and/or buggy and definitely unintuitive.