# Inbox messages stay unread

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

For a few months now (I'm not sure how long), messages in my inbox stay unread after I click on them and read them.  The only way to remove the unread marker is to click on the envelope icon so it converts to the open envelope icon.

Is this a bug, or have I accidentally changed some setting somewhere?

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424147/inbox-notifications-not-consistently-marked-as-read-after-clicking-title#comment955812_424147

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421735/ Pretty much go to the [meta-tag:global-inbox] tag and you'll find this issue complained about repeatedly...

Comment: You mean the inbox - global inbox is different. It also has *different problem with unread messages*. If you change the page, then clicking on a message does not mark it as read. Even if you go from page 1 to page 2 and then back to page 1. You have to reload the browser tab after changing the page of messages and only then clicking on one marks it as read. The inbox is in the top right on most regular pages. The global inbox is in your network profile. Easiest way to get there is to middle-click on the top-right inbox icon.

Comment: @VLAZ:  thanks.  I don't see an "inbox" tag, but I've removed the "global-inbox" tag.

Comment: @VLAZ According to the global-inbox tag wiki that tag is actually about the "regular" inbox, which is also global (i.e., it contains messages from all sites in the network). The uber-global inbox at https://stackexchange.com does not seem to have its own separate tag.

Comment: It would not make sense to have a "global global-inbox" tag on the SO specific meta